# How to debug solution of a dependent dll with two instance of visual studio?

Tags: debugging, .net-assembly, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files, dll-dependency

I have I Sharepoint Timer job solution that has a dependent .dll of another solution . 
To debug 1st one, I just need to attach to the OWSTIMER.EXE process. But I'd need to debug the 2nd solution When the 1st call some method of the 2nd. 
I've been trying something like attaching the 2nd SLN to the 1st one process but it doesn't hit! I've thinking to attach both SLN to OWSTIMER.EXE but it's not possible.
I've tried to attach the 2nd to OWSTIMER.EXE(OWSTIMER.EXE is using the 1st SNL but the dependent dll is the same one of the 2nd) so theoretically this should work! :/
I confess that probably something that is not completely clear about it.
Has anybody any idea how should be this done? And (most important thing) could anybody explain me what's wrong with my reasoning???

Comment: You might be able to create an entirely different sln file that references the 2 solutions in question. Nesting Solutions may allow you to pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need to open a solution to debug its code.

I assume that you want to set breakpoints in the 2-nd solution. Simply go to File-> Open in VS and open a file from second solution, and place a breakpoint. It will work :)

Also, if everything else fails you can set breakpoints even without the code - just go to Debug->Breakpoints->new breakpoint and give the name of the namespace.class.method(), VS will resolve it to a correct method or number of methods if you have different overloads with the same name.

So do you need anything else or just to set up breakpoints in the 2-nd solution?